# getting number from external website

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I need to get a number from this website: [Current STC price](http://www.greenenergytrading.com.au/certificates/todays-pricing) which displays a market driven figure: STCs.

i tried this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.greenenergytrading.com.au/certificates/todays-pricing');

$html = strip_tags($html);
```

which leaves me with a long string. I then tried to remove anything before the figure I'm after, assuming that the text wont change:

```
$html = preg_replace('/.*Current STC price/', '', $html);
```

However, this doesnt work. it seems to work on online RexExp tester but not in production. also, is this a reasonable approach? 
cheers

Comment: "Assuming that the text wont change" is a huge assumption.  Make sure, if you stay with this approach, that you actually test that the text did not change.

Comment: That's correct. any better idea? i also just tried preg_match, which again works fine in RegExp test software but not in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match with the $matches parameter provided to extract all ocurrences of  from the website source and store them in an array. Then, just access the first element of the array.

Check out the documentation for preg_match here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

EDIT: Oh, I just saw your comment that you tried preg_match already. What regexp's have you tried? Have you tried something like "/$[0-9]{1}/" ?

Comment: ok, got a result now, which does not so much rely on the text but on the fact that the figure i'm after comes first. `$html = preg_match('/\$[0-9]{2}/', $html, $matches);`